# How to get the value from nested json object of the given JSON below

Tags: json, node.js

```
{
  "docs":{
    "count":2,
    "users":[
      {
        "_id":"5acc820965c9633fbd851ff7",
        "title":"Yamaha Fazer",
        "description":"this is the dummy description for the yamaha bike. ",
        "image_url":"http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_52c470899a2e1_1.JPG"
      },
      {
        "_id":"5acc8283aa63b6401ac290f0",
        "title":"Apache RR 310",
        "description":"this is the dummy description for the Apache RR 310 bike. ",
        "image_url":"http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_52c470899a2e1_1.JPG"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What value do you need to get? What's your expected output?

Comment: value for count and user.. i am getting error on doing like.
docs.count

Comment: `var data = <your JSON object here>; var count = data.docs.count;`

Answer (score 1):

Should be like this

d = myObj.docs.count;

u = myObj.docs.users;

Comment: I have done like
   var myObj=data;
    var count=myObj.docs.count;


    var count=myObj.docs.count;
                        ^
It give an error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Comment: can you show the full code you wrote the get the count?

Comment: To access the count:
  count = myObj.docs.count;

To get the title of the user object:
  title =  myObj.docs.users[0]["title"];

this is tested and working fine.

Comment: Please mark as answer if the solution was successful.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this,Its Working Fine.

 var demo = data.docs;
            alert(demo.count); ///Count
                var User = demo.users;  ///users
                for (j = 0; User.length > j; j++) {
                    alert(User[j]._id);
                    alert(User[j].title);
                    alert(User[j].description);
                    alert(User[j].image_url);
            }
```

Comment: can you please refer next answer @VarunSingh.

Answer (score 0):

```
    json:
     var data = {
                    "docs": {
                        "count": 2,
                        "users": [
                          {
                              "_id": "5acc820965c9633fbd851ff7",
                              "title": "Yamaha Fazer",
                              "description": "this is the dummy description for the yamaha bike. ",
                              "image_url": "http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_52c470899a2e1_1.JPG"
                          },
                          {
                              "_id": "5acc8283aa63b6401ac290f0",
                              "title": "Apache RR 310",
                              "description": "this is the dummy description for the Apache RR 310 bike. ",
                              "image_url": "http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_52c470899a2e1_1.JPG"
                          }
                        ]
                    }
                }

javascript:
var demo = data.docs;
            alert(demo.count); ///Count
                var User = demo.users;  ///users
                for (j = 0; User.length > j; j++) {
                    alert(User[j]._id);
                    alert(User[j].title);
                    alert(User[j].description);
                    alert(User[j].image_url);
            }
```